# pdf function purpose too vague to understand

Tags: r, pdf, pdf-generation, histogram

I am trying to convert a histogram to a pdf file.

```
       pdf(filename="")
       hist1<-hist(mat1, main="Histogram", xlab="Increments")
       dev.off()
```

However, the pdf function that converts your histogram image to a pdf is not working... does this function vaguely specify the name of the file that your creating for the pdf i.e. pdf(filename="C:hist") for which I get the following error:

```
              "Error in pdf(filename = "hist") : 
            unused argument (filename = "hist")"
```

Or do you have to specify a pathway to put it into the directory you want i.e. pdf("C:Users/clarkson/rpractice/Condition1Traj1")? for which I get the following error:

```
       Error in pdf(file = "C:Users/clarkson/rpractice/hist") : 
     cannot open file 'C:Users/clarkson/rpractice/hist'
```

It's clear that I'm misunderstanding the function of this command entirely from the 'help(pdf)' page because neither of the above commands work...

Can anyone explain if the pdf function is used to express the destination file's name and if so how or is it for something else (like sourcing a file)?

Comment: each of your commands have a typo; `file="hist.pdf"` or `C:/Users...`

Comment: Also, if you're having issues with this, I recommend rmarkdown, it's very straightforward to make pdfs, and doesn't require mucking about with outputting devices to pdf

Comment: Have you tried `?pdf` ?

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron noted, your application isn't even getting off the ground with the file opening, as the path to your input is missing its first slash between the drive letter and folder name; i.e. either "C:/Users/clarkson/rpractice/hist" (forward slash) or "C:\Users\clarkson\rpractice\hist" (escaped backslash) should be used.

In addition, it's not clear whether "hist" is intended to be your input PDF file (i.e. hist.pdf) or the name of your lowest folder, so you may or may not be missing a file extension or entire filename on the end, depending on how your code is receiving (or concatenating) the name of the file to be opened.

Consider for testing purposes just omitting the path reference altogether (temporarily at least), and dropping your input PDF document right into your local folder, where you know the application is going to find it when you give it just the filename alone. Once you have the basic process worked out, you can then relocate your file opening to be looking at the intended relative or absolute path location where your actual input documents will be found.